# How to rectify spring boot entity manager factory?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jdbc

[image: Spring Boot Entity Manager Factory]
I am new to the spring boot application and I am having an issue related to some entity manager factory. I am trying to run my application on localhost. I attached a picture of error below:

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because no database dependency is found in classpath so no entityManagerFactory bean is created.

If you add a DB dependency, like H2 (in memory DB), spring will detect it into classpath and will create the missing bean.

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

You can add what DB dependency you want to (mysql, postgres, etc), for sake of the example, I added H2.

Comment: Okay, yes, I found. This is missing. Thank you.